# create route that points to a microservice method with zuul

Tags: netflix-zuul

Is it possible to create a route that points to a method inside a microservice?, I have a microservice called MsCargosAbonos that is discovered by my eureka server, inside my microservice I have a method called pago, my zuul application url is http://localhost:8000, I can call the microservice like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/mscargosabonos/pago
```

So I want to change the url above to:

```
http://localhost:8000/ejecutarPago
```

Is it possible to do this with zuul?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you directly want to call the method from zuul routing. Is that what you are really asking for?

Comment: I donot know if you can directly call a method in a microservice from zuul but if you have a mapping in the microservice controller than the appropriate method should be invoked. Zuul is for routing so it can route to a specific URL but not to a method thats what my thinking is. Hope this helps

Comment: If I understood is something like the code that I posted below?

Comment: yess... if you are using Eureka you can use the service id too... is this not working

Comment: so instead of using "http://localhost:8000" can I use "http://mspago"?, I think that instead of "url" property I need to use "id" property right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify my application.yml like this:

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    pago:  
      path: /pago/**
      url: http://localhost:8000/api/mspago/
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do this so if someone has a better idea please share it with me, thanks.

Comment: what you have seems correct in case you want use serviceId which is the id with which the service is registered in eureka. Check this url http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html for you I think the serviceID wont work because the path and the urls are different for you ...